# How to add a new record from unbound fields of two tables in to a subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Hey there Good Day can anyone help me please?
I got a mainform and a subform and Ive created a query to join the two tables and ive tried to use the query to insert fields which is unbound, my subform fields which im getting from my join query if I insert into my fields it says and click the Add button I get a error it says:
Run-time error '3134':
Syntax error in insert into statement.

Code I used below:

```
Private Sub Add_Click() 
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO PlantTransactionQuery(TransactionID,Plant Number,Categories,Description,Location,TransactionDate,Opening_Hours,Closing_Hours,Hours Worked,Fuel,Fuel Cons Fuel/Hours,Hour Meter Replaced,Comments)" & _
"VALUES(" & Me.txt13 & ",'" & Me.txt1 & "','" & Me.txt2 & "','" & Me.txt3 & "','" & Me.txt4 & "','" & Me.txt5 & "','" & Me.txt6 & "','" & Me.txt7 & "','" & Me.txt8 & "','" & Me.txt9 & "','" & Me.txt10 & "'," & Me.txt11 & "," & Me.txt12 & ")"
PlantTransactionsubform.Form.Requery 
End Sub
```

I dont know if u can insert into a query and i dont know which name I must put into brackets for reserved name.
Any help will be much appreciated of how to add two tables in a subform in a button onclick on the same page or even maybe i made a mistake in my code for me everything looks good. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to put square brackets `[]` around any table or field name that

- contains spaces or "funny characters", or
- is an [Access reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).

Try this instead:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO PlantTransactionQuery (TransactionID,[Plant Number],Categories,Description,Location,TransactionDate,Opening_Hours,Closing_Hours,[Hours Worked],Fuel,[Fuel Cons Fuel/Hours],[Hour Meter Replaced],Comments) " & _
"VALUES (" & Me.txt13 & ",'" & Me.txt1 & "','" & Me.txt2 & "','" & Me.txt3 & "','" & Me.txt4 & "','" & Me.txt5 & "','" & Me.txt6 & "','" & Me.txt7 & "','" & Me.txt8 & "','" & Me.txt9 & "','" & Me.txt10 & "'," & Me.txt11 & "," & Me.txt12 & ")"
```

### Edit

You can make SQL statements easier to verify visually if you break them up line-by-line, something like this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO [PlantTransactionQuery] (" & _
                "[TransactionID], " & _
                "[Plant Number], " & _
                "[Categories], " & _
                "[Description], " & _
                "[Location], " & _
                "[TransactionDate], " & _
                "[Opening_Hours], " & _
                "[Closing_Hours], " & _
                "[Hours Worked], " & _
                "[Fuel], " & _
                "[Fuel Cons Fuel/Hours], " & _
                "[Hour Meter Replaced], " & _
                "[Comments] " & _
            ") VALUES (" & _
                Me.txt13 & ", " & _
                "'" & Me.txt1 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt2 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt3 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt4 & "', " & _
                "#" & Me.txt5 & "#, " & _
                "'" & Me.txt6 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt7 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt8 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt9 & "', " & _
                "'" & Me.txt10 & "', " & _
                Me.txt11 & ", " & _
                Me.txt12 & " " & _
            ")"
```

The 3061 error message "Too few parameters..." can happen if a field (column) name is mis-spelled, or a field name that happens to be a reserved word is not enclosed in square brackets. I've edited the query above so *all* table and column names are bracketed, just to be safe.

Also, check that you *are* quoting strings and *are not* quoting numbers. A mistake there could also result in the aforementioned error.

As for [TransactionDate], you probably should un-bind the text box for consistency. Notice that the value for that field is enclosed in hash marks (`#`) instead of single quotes. You can add a "date" input mask to the text box, or you can use something like...

```
Format(CDate(Me.txt5), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

...to format the date for you.

Finally, be aware that building SQL strings like that leaves you open to ***SQL injection*** problems, so you might also consider replacing that `.Execute` with something like

```
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("[PlantTransactionQuery]", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst![TransactionID] = CLng(Me.txt13)
rst![Plant Number] = Me.txt1
rst![Categories] = Me.txt2
...
rst![Comments] = Me.txt12
rst.Update
```

Comment: im getting a run time error '3061' Too few parameters expected 1.

Comment: only my TransactionDate is a bound field because i dont know how to create a date field in my Access form any suggestions